# Iterate through given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

```
df = 
0   20
1   19
2   18
3   17
4   16
```

I am iterating with a loop:

```
for k in df:
    af = AffinityPropagation(preference=k).fit(X)
    labels = af.labels_
    score = silhouette_score(frechet, labels)
    print("Preference: {0}, Silhouette score: {1}".format(k,score))
```

I get 1 number. But I need/want to get dataframe with numbers in the length of df `len(df)`

Comment: iterating over a dataframe means iterating over its columns - and there is only one...

Comment: I mean, every value of the `df`

Comment: You probably meant `for index, k in df.iterrows()`

Comment: @Mamed I know, and `for k in df` does not do what you mean, but what I explained. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `iterrows` as @CodeDifferently points out in his comment above.

Here is an example:

Where df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:range(20,0,-1)})
```

Then using your method:

```
for k in df:
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
0
```

This zero is the column header for a dataframe.  You are iterating thow the dataframe column names.

Using `iterrows`:

```
for _,k in df.iterrows():
    print(k.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Here you are getting each row of the dataframe as series, and using `iloc` you are getting the first and only value in the rows for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You almost never need to iterate over a DataFrame. Columns are basically NumPy arrays and have array-like 'elementwise' superpowers. (You ~never need to iterate over NumPy arrays either.)

Maybe formulate your task as a function and use the `apply()` method on the DataFrame or Series. This 'applies' a function to every item in a column without the need for a loop.

But if you really only have one column like this, why use a DataFrame at all? Just use a NumPy array (or get at it with the column's `values` attribute).